# Antlr4 PLSQL Errors

Tags: python, parsing, plsql, antlr4

I'm trying to test the Antlr4 (Oracle) PLSQL grammar, but really struggling. I might have confused things by having followed 2 or 3 different guides.

I performed the following steps, starting with installation, on Ubuntu 22.04.

Install packages, but not sure I ended up using these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3-antlr4
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install antlr-plsql
pip3 install antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3
```

I then switched to another guide, which seemed simpler and more self-contained:

```
mkdir lib
cd lib
curl -O https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar
cd ..
mkdir grammars
cd grammars
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4
cd ..
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py
```

This gives me:

```
├── grammars
│   ├── PlSqlLexer.g4
│   └── PlSqlParser.g4
├── lib
│   └── antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar
├── PlSqlLexerBase.py
├── PlSqlParserBase.py
```

Generate the Python 3 modules from the grammars:

```
java -jar ./lib/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars/*g4
```

The result is very long error message:

```
error(50): /home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlLexer.g4:1:0: syntax error: 
'{"payload":
   {"allShortcutsEnabled":false,"fileTree":
      {"sql/plsql":
          {"items":
             [ {"name":"CSharp","path":"sql/plsql/CSharp","contentType":"directory"},
               {"name":"Cpp","path":"sql/plsql/Cpp","contentType":"directory"},
               {"name":"Dart","path":"sql/plsql/Dart","contentType":"directory"},
.
.
.
"grammars-v4",
"showInvalidCitationWarning":false,
"citationHelpUrl":"https://docs.github.com/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-citation-files",
"actionsOnboardingTip":null},
"truncated":false,"viewable":true,"workflowRedirectUrl":null,"symbols":{"timed_out":false,"not_analyzed":true,"symbols":[]}},
"copilotInfo":null,
"copilotAccessAllowed":false,
"csrf_tokens":{"/antlr/grammars-v4/branches":{"post":"B-JVTx4hyskRLh-IIK4rWkAi5MsB-02SSXgjgq9nYNzDI1ZfW5iKO2EvjBCRVSAFlOtcSNnBT47ACuB9TmN_KA"},"/repos/preferences":{"post":"GKOXPKaenoTNYzUHdAFAZKMu0-z4ENu8r5KmHmhUiOKs4HBOuNY9PVTbSAMl7rKPVfBwRCJRpTY72nxBH5PotA"}}},
"title":"grammars-v4/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4 at master · antlr/grammars-v4"}'
 came as a complete surprise to me
```

Tried this as well but got the same result:

```
java -Xmx500M -cp "./lib/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars/*g4
```

Comment: That grammar does not work for 4.9.3. Use at least [4.12](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/c8889147b0367c5286cba827dff57d0231998d40/sql/plsql/desc.xml#L3), or better would be [4.13.1](https://pypi.org/project/antlr4-python3-runtime/). But, I don't know if it works for Python3 since [it's not listed as ported](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/c8889147b0367c5286cba827dff57d0231998d40/sql/plsql/desc.xml#L4).

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks. I tried 4.13.1 and also changing the language to Java but I get the same error, so maybe the error is in the grammar file(s), but these are downloaded from the repo so not sure where to go from here. The error is so long that its not at all clear what the actual error is.

Comment: I think the `wget` downloaded the github JSON file list instead of the actual files themselves. I've seen this before. Check 
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py in your browser, and the file you think you downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the Python file generated eventually.

I found another pair of grammar files set from

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql.

From here I downloaded as follows:

```
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py

wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4

mv PlSql*g4 grammars
```

When I then run:

```
java -jar ./lib/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars/*g4
```

I get the following generated in `grammars`:

```
grammars-v4-master  PlSqlLexer.interp  PlSqlParserBase.py  PlSqlParserListener.py  __pycache__
master.zip          PlSqlLexer.py      PlSqlParser.g4      PlSqlParser.py          runPLSQL.py
PlSqlLexer.g4       PlSqlLexer.tokens  PlSqlParser.interp  PlSqlParser.tokens
```